# Multiple CreateFileA calls return same File Handle

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, handle

I have a routine to open COM Ports using CreateFileA.
The function is created as a DLL and I have an EXE(using VS2010) to make calls to open different COM Ports.
An observation is that if I use the same EXE to open different ports, The File Handle Number returned is different.
If I open multiple instances of the EXE and open different COM Ports, the File Handle Number returned is the same.
Eg->
1 exe is used to open COM Port 11,12,13,14 and they return File Handle Numbers - 0x200, 0x210, 0x21c, 0x220
4 exes, each opens one COM Port, and they all return File Handle Number - 0x200.

I would like to know if this is due to windows threading such that each instance of the exe has a separate thread and hence the same file number?
I am not having any problem communicating with the Ports using my exe.
Any clues understanding this will be helpful. (Another application is trying to use this DLL and is having issues with the same File Handle number being returned)

Thanks
Aditya

Answer (score 3):

Value of the HANDLE is valid only within one process. To be more clear, handles are implemented as indexes (or offsets) to some kernel object table. This table is stored in kernel memory and is assigned to a particular process, i.e. every process has its own, different object table.

Since handles are just offsets to some table, and those tables are completely different for different processes, you cannot pass (or compare) values of HANDLE for different processes.

Back to your case, if your application is simple and deterministic, you have good chances to obtain the same value of HANDLE when you re-run the application, simply because OS is likely to fill in the object table deterministically. However it is not guaranteed and you cannot rely on it.

Since handles cannot be passed literally to different process, Windows has [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function that could be used if one process wants to pass the same object to other process. Notice, with DuplicateHandle, the source handle only could be used in source process, while destination handle could be used in only destination process.

Comment: Thanks Seva. Can I keep track of the process and the table offset together? In my exe that is?

Comment: @Aditya, this information is not exposed through any public API. WindDbg debugger can access it through internal structures. Check out !handle command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563187(v=vs.85).aspx. Running it without parameters displays all handles in the process, along with type of the object (File/Directory/Registry Key/Memory Section/Semaphore, etc).